# In my multi-dog household, can I expect to be able to take my dogs to the backyard all together?

Tags: dogs

Background:  I'm currently crate-training and house breaking three chihuahua/chihuahua mixes. And I'm thinking of adding a fourth chihuahua to the new pack-in-the-making. But the only real hang-up is the added time it requires to take each dog to the backyard to relieve itself one by one. Which leads me to my question.

Question:  Once crate-training is more or less at an end, and the dogs have transitioned to being a pack, can I look forward to leading them all to the backyard together to relieve themselves? Or is it that people usually find this to be impossible and end up having to take each dog out individually forever?

Note: I already have a no-play or hangout policy after relieving themselves in the yard...and it's not a place where we play otherwise either.

Comment: I don't see why not.  Do the dogs get along?

Comment: Well the third we added just a few days ago, so he's barely been introduced, but they're fine being in adjacent crates. Whenever we let the other two together (a 1-2 year old female and a 4 month old male) the boy without fail initiates play fighting and they battle until we stop them or until they get tired.

Comment: Play fighting is what puppies (and middle age and a adult dogs) do.

Comment: I understand that, and we let them do it and quite enjoy it ourselves.

Comment: Why do you have a no play or hangout policy in the yard?  I've never heard of that before.

Comment: @Victoria, it's to train them that when they go out in our small enclosed yard, it's for business.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see no problem.  I always let my dogs out at the same time and if they need to go then they go.